# itunes connect app analytics - number of app updates

Tags: itunes, applications, app-store-connect

We just released a new version of our app and I wanted to see how many users have updated to the new version.

In the past it was fairly straightforward to see the number of app updates for your users. You could set a filter to see updates and then download a csv etc. I have been digging around in the latest version of itunes connect and I just can't find a way to see the number of updates. I was reading through the documentation [here](http://help.apple.com/itc/appanalytics/#/itc623752a8d) and a few of the categories specifically say they don't include updates but nothing about what does include updates.Does anyone know how to get this report out of itunes connect app analytics?

Answer (score 5):

I was looking in the wrong place. Sales and Trends is the place to check for number of app updates. To check how many users have updated go to itunes connect >sales and trends. Click Add Filters > Transaction type > updates.

Comment: On Sales & Trends make sure you select "Sales" -> "Units" or this filter won't work